# C++ - Accepting Multiple Clients

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, winsock

I'm really having troubles accepting multiple clients into a Socket Server. 
Currently, one client is allowed. When the next client tries to join, the app freezes and does nothing.

I've done a ton of research the past week on this, but nothing seems to satisfy me. 
I've saw tutorials on the multi-threading, but I wasn't given enough information on the function to actually work with it (yes, I'm a very visual learner, which isn't the best for programming).

So I was just wondering if I could get a decent to great explanation on how to do this. 
Maybe even an example can be thrown in there, if at all possible.

I've also saw this `select()` function, in which I wasn't given enough information on, either.

Although I do have a running and working server, Multithreading is really starting to mess with my head, I'm very confused on the situation and how it works.

So if I could be given an explanation and example, that'd be great!

This is my current server code, how would I enable multiple clients?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <vector>

bool gamerunning = true;
bool srvr_connect = false;
int srvr_rec = 0;

int main() {
    WSAData wsa;
    WORD Version = MAKEWORD(2, 1);

    WSAStartup(Version, &wsa);

    SOCKET Listen;
    SOCKET Connect;

    Listen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    Connect = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    SOCKADDR_IN Server;

    Server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.2.4");
    Server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    Server.sin_port = htons(100);

    bind(Listen, (SOCKADDR*)&Server, sizeof(Server));

    listen(Listen, 4);

    int size = sizeof(Server);

    std::cout << "Your server has been started!\nConnecting...\n";

    Connect = accept(Listen, (SOCKADDR*)&Server, &size);

    while (gamerunning) {
        if (Connect != NULL) {
            srvr_connect = true;
            std::cout << "Welcome to player: " << srvr_rec << "\n";
            srvr_rec +=1;
        }
        if (srvr_connect == true) {
            if (test_frame == 0) {
                std::cout << "Connection Sent!\nConnection Has Been Breached!\nPlayers Are Now Able to Join Your Server!\n";
                test_frame +=1;
            }
        }
    }
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, this works great for my client. But only accepts one. 
How can I fix this up to work?

Comment: A single-threaded `select`-based server should be your first step. It's conceptually simple and reasonably powerful for training purposes.

Comment: @KerrekSB It's reasonably powerful for production purposes... Nginx...

Comment: What kind of networking code have you written that worked?

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm not sure how select works? I looked it up, but I'm having trouble understanding it.

Comment: @brianbeuning Just a basic server-client socket using WinSock2.It works fine, so that's not the problem.

Comment: @user2009320: In a loop, essentially. `man select` should have an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
// define a list of sockets
// create the socket you are going to accept on and add the socket to the list
while( true ) {
    // use the list to build the read set
    select( .. read-set .. )
    for( all sockets in the read-set ) {
         if( socket == accept-socket ) {
               // do accept
               // add the new socket to the list
         } else {
               // read data from the socket
         }
    }
}
```

You use select() like this

```
fd_set readfds;
fd_set writefds;
fd_set exceptfds;
FD_ZERO( readfds );
FD_ZERO( writefds );
FD_ZERO( exceptfds );
int nfds = 0;
for( all socket x in socket list ) {
    FD_SET( x, readfds )
    nfds++;
}
int rc = select( nfds, & readfds, & writefds, & exceptfds, 0 );
for( all socket x in socket list ) {
    if( FD_ISSET( x, readfds ) ) {
        // socket x has something to read or accept
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, before I add this into my code, how does this work? For example, how does this "loop" (or whatever you want to call it) the socket?

Comment: "cannot convert 'readfds' from type 'fd_set' to type 'fd_set*'" when I change it to "fd_set* readfds", then I get the same error in 'select' for 'fd_set**' to 'fd_set'